# prove the following identity holds for all real numbers x. [4x]=[x]+[x+1/4]+[x+2/4]+[x+3/4]

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The brackets are the floor function. so [4.3] would be 4 and [-2.4] would be -3 I am trying to prove this by cases. I think that I should prove each case first such as [x] first and then [x+1/4] and on but I'm having trouble proving it in generality

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics, not programming. It might be better suited to http://math.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1):

Prove it in four cases.

- Case 1: `0 <= x - [x] < 1/4`
- Case 2: `1/4 <= x - [x] < 1/2`
- Case 3: `1/2 <= x - [x] < 3/4`
- Case 4: `3/4 <= x - [x] < 1`

In each case, `[x]`, `[x+1/4]`, `[x+2/4]`, `[x+3/4]`, and `[4x]` are easy to express in terms of `[x]`.

Comment: Simple, elegant, easy to understand.